# How can i change the opacity of my SVG line with a text input?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to change the opacity of my SVG line with a text input but i can't find any resolutions for that problem.

I am trying to change the opacity in this var. Whole code i have is down bellow

I did everything :D

```
    <script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var s = Snap("#iconDiv");
            Snap.load("Entwurf.svg", function(f) {

               var L_KOM_AUT = f.select("#L_KOM_AUT");
               L_KOM_AUT.attr({
                   fill: '#101010',
                   opacity:0.00001,
                   });


            s.append(f);
            });          
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="mail">Opacity:</label>
        <input type="text" name="opacity" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div id="iconDiv"></div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a EventListener on the input tag and set the opacity to the value of the text input.

Documentation on EventListeners: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var s = Snap("#iconDiv");
  Snap.load("Entwurf.svg", function(f) {

    var L_KOM_AUT = f.select("#L_KOM_AUT");
    L_KOM_AUT.attr({
      fill: '#101010',
      opacity:0.00001,
    });

    s.append(f);
  });       

  var textInput = document.querySelector('input');
  var svg = document.querySelector('#L_KOM_AUT');

  textInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    svg.style.opacity = this.value;
  }
};
```

Comment: sorry but i am really new to coding where exactly do i put this stuff? can you maybe show it in my code that i posted?

Comment: Between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:skyblue;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:seagreen;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="black" />
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="40" fill="black" opacity="0.3" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i know how to change the opacity. But what i asked is how i can change the opacity by typing in a text box for example : 0.5, then click a button and the opacity will change automatically